# How to debug Windows shutdown issues?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, debug

I have Windows 10 Home edition. Since the last update, the computer takes forever to shutdown. Here's what I tried:

1. Right-click Start
2. Select *Windows PowerShell (Admin)*
3. Click "Yes" on the UAC prompt
4. Run the command `shutdown /s /f /t 0`

Nothing happens, the command just hangs and does not return me to the prompt. When I wait for about 15 minutes (!), the computer finally shuts down. During this time, I can use the computer as normal.

I would like to investigate which program/service is causing this issue. I have checked the Event Viewer (`eventvwr.exe`) but I wouldn't know which log to look at. I have also checked Task Manager but it shows no processes that take up high CPU, disk or memory usage.

How can I debug this issue?

***Edit:*** *I have solved the problem by unplugging my external USB memory card reader. Apparently, this device prevented the computer from shutting down. The question still stands, however. How could I have found this problem by debugging the shutdown process, rather than by a lucky guess?*

Comment: Try initial repairs to see if that helps shutdown. Open cmd.exe and run in order:  (1) dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /startcomponentcleanup   (2)  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   (3) SFC /SCANNOW  .  When done, restart and test.

Comment: If John's comment doesn't help, try booting into safe mode and seeing if shutdown functions properly there. If it does, there could be a faulty driver causing the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Note: Windows is evolving continuously and details may vary between versions.)

**Controlling shutdown behavior**

Before going into tracing the shutdown, I remark that a wait time for
shutdown of about 15 minutes is abnormal - this should normally be at most
a couple of minutes.
I suggest to check in the registry under the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
whether you have set any of the following items:

- `WaitToKillAppTimeout` : (default 20 seconds)
  Time for open applications to clean up and save their data before offering to close them.
- `HungAppTimeout` : (default 5 seconds)
  How many seconds Windows waits before considering applications unresponsive.
- `AutoEndTasks` : (default is 0)
  Set to `1` to automatically close programs at shutdown without asking for
  your permission.

For more information see
[Control How Long Windows Waits Before Killing Apps at Shutdown](https://www.howtogeek.com/282062/control-how-long-windows-waits-before-killing-apps-at-shutdown/).

**Enable verbose shutdown messages**

If verbose logging isn't enabled, only normal status messages are shown,
such as "Applying your personal settings..." or "Applying computer settings..."
when you start up, shut down, log on, or log off from the computer.
If verbose logging is enabled, you'll receive additional information,
such as "RPCSS is starting" or "Waiting for machine group policies to finish....".

To enable verbose status messages:

- Run regedit
- Position to the following registry key:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
- Create a DWORD value named `verbosestatus` and set it to `1`

**Tracing the shutdown process in details**

The process and tools described below can also be used to trace the
boot.

***Installing the tools***

- Download the
  [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)
  file `winsdksetup.exe`
- Run it and select to install only the "Windows Performance Tools"
  (not the full install)
- Reboot.

***Creating the trace log***

- In a Command Prompt that is run as an administrator, position to:

  ```
    cd %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit
  ```
- Do a reboot trace like this:

  ```
    xbootmgr -trace shutdown -traceFlags BASE+DIAG+LATENCY -noPrepReboot
  ```

  After the boot, it will generate a trace within two minutes.

***Viewing the trace log***

- Run the Windows Performance Analyzer (`wpa.exe`)
- Use the menu *File > Open* to open the trace log inside the folder
   `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit`
- The detailed trace is found in the "Analysis" tab.
- For specific shutdown information, use menu
  *Profiles > Apply > Browse Catalog* and select "FullBoot.Shutdown.wpaprofile".